# Android: change layout/content of widget in new app version

Tags: android, layout, widget

What are the best practices of changing widget layout in new (updated) version of application? How to deal with existing widgets, when new version provides updated, better ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must show a popup to users stating "what's new in this version" and ask them to re-install the widgets. There is no way via API to do that.